# pigpio hardware PWM for servos

Tags: pi-4, python-3, pwm, pigpio, pi-gpio

My goal is to build a pan/tilt system.

this works fine:

```
import pigpio
pi = pigpio.pi()
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(13,1055)
```

2 questions:

- is pi.[set_servo_pulsewidth](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_servo_pulsewidth) using hardware PWM
  (I prefer [HW PWM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100641/whats-the-difference-between-soft-pwm-and-pwm))
- Can I adjust the speed of the servo
  (reach an extent slower - more time to pan)

Comment: @joan any insight?

Comment: servos, similar to hobby servos, usually run at a fixed speed .... if you want to change the transit time, then you will have to pause during travel

Comment: Joan has indicated that [timing is provided by hardware](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/110794/servo-motor-keep-shaking-while-using-software-pwm-to-drive).  Not sure that is the same as using the built-in raspberry PWM hardware.

Comment: There's [an example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101742/is-there-a-way-to-slow-down-servo-movement-speed) of the pauses suggested by jsotola

Comment: i am not talking about the control signal timing ... i am talking about the speed at which the servo moves ... the two are not related